# Change Select option based on input field dynamically while typing

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have an input field and a select field in my project. I would like to change the select option dynamically, based on what the user is typing (a combination of letters and numbers). The user can also select it himself, the dynamic change is sort of a helper.

```
<input id="userInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here">

<select id="sel" class="form-control form-control-xl">
  <option selected>Choose one</option>
  <option value="1">Dog</option>
  <option value="2">Cat</option>
  <option value="3">Lizard</option>
  <option value="4">Fish</option>
</select>
```

The option is based on logic like so

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');

if (userInput firstletter is Z and followed by numbers) {
    $('#sel').val('1').change(); // Dog
} else if (userInput beginsWith === AB and endsWith === YZ with numbers between) {
    $('#sel').val('2').change(); // Cat
} else if (userInput endsWith === XX) {
    $('#sel').val('3').change(); // Lizard
} else if (userInput beginsWith === 222) {
    $('#sel').val('4').change(); // Fish
}
```

What is the correct way to change the option similarly to a search field with autosuggest?

Comment: Use regex.......

Comment: In what way does the entered alphanumeric string relate to the options in the `<select>`?

Comment: The type of alphanumeric string determines the option by the order string, eg. `Z12345` id for Dog, `AB12345YZ` is for Cat.

Comment: [Select2](https://select2.org/) or [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) would do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `regex` for each of your pattern as a `dictionary`. Then you can loop and match it when the textbox value change.

```js
var dict = []; // create an empty array

window.onload = function(){

dict.push({key:   "1",  value: "^z+[0-9]*$"}); //firstletter is Z and followed by numbers
dict.push({key:   "2",  value: "^AB.[0-9]*YZ$"}); //beginsWith === AB and endsWith === YZ with numbers between
dict.push({key:   "3",  value: "^Cat$"});
dict.push({key:   "4",  value: "^Lizard$"});
dict.push({key:   "5",  value: "^Fish$"});

}


function test()
{

var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
var sel= document.getElementById('sel');
sel.value = "";
var isMatched = false;

 for(var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++)
    {
        var reg = eval("/" + dict[i].value + "/gi");
        
        isMatched = reg.test(userInput);
        console.log(i + " " +userInput + " " + isMatched + " Key: " + dict[i].key);
        
        if (isMatched)
        {
          sel.value = dict[i].key;
          break;
        }   
      }
}
```

```html
<input id="userInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" onchange="test()" onchange="test()">

<select id="sel" class="form-control form-control-xl">
  <option value="" selected>Choose one</option>
  <option value="1">First Letter Z and then numbers</option>
  <option value="2">Begins with AB and number in between adn ends with YZ</option>
  <option value="3">Cat</option>
  <option value="4">Lizard</option>
  <option value="5">Fish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is great! One question - Sometimes I have to do an action to get the value to change, eg. clicking outside of the input field. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Try other events `onKeyUp` or `orKeyDown`